# Subcaptions for TikZ pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I'd like to put (sub)captions under the diagrams on the right hand side of the equation in the following code. For example, I'd like to label them (a) through (e).

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzstyle{hackennode}=[draw,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt]
\tikzstyle{hackenline}=[line width=3pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
{\Large
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5]
    \draw[densely dashed] (-1,-1) -- (3,-1);
    \node[hackennode] (0) at (0,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (2) at (0,1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (3) at (0,2) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (0) -- (1) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (1) -- (2) -- (3) {};
    \node[hackennode] (10) at (1,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (11) at (1,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (12) at (1,1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (13) at (1,2) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (10) -- (11) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (11) -- (12) -- (13) {};
    \node[hackennode] (20) at (2,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (21) at (2,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (22) at (2,1) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (20) -- (21);
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (21) -- (22);
\end{tikzpicture}
=
\left \{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5]
        \draw[densely dashed] (-1,-1) -- (3,-1);
        \node[hackennode] (10) at (1,-1) {};
        \node[hackennode] (11) at (1,0) {};
        \node[hackennode] (12) at (1,1) {};
        \node[hackennode] (13) at (1,2) {};
        \draw[hackenline,blue] (10) -- (11) {};
        \draw[hackenline,red] (11) -- (12) -- (13) {};
        \node[hackennode] (20) at (2,-1) {};
        \node[hackennode] (21) at (2,0) {};
        \node[hackennode] (22) at (2,1) {};
        \draw[hackenline,red] (20) -- (21);
        \draw[hackenline,blue] (21) -- (22);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\tikz[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5] \node[inner sep=0] at (0,-1) {,\,};
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5]
    \draw[densely dashed] (-1,-1) -- (3,-1);
    \node[hackennode] (0) at (0,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (2) at (0,1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (3) at (0,2) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (0) -- (1) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (1) -- (2) -- (3) {};
    \node[hackennode] (10) at (1,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (11) at (1,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (12) at (1,1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (13) at (1,2) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (10) -- (11) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (11) -- (12) -- (13) {};
    \node[hackennode] (20) at (2,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (21) at (2,0) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (20) -- (21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\middle |
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5]
    \draw[densely dashed] (-1,-1) -- (3,-1);
    \node[hackennode] (0) at (0,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (2) at (0,1) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (0) -- (1) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (1) -- (2)  {};
    \node[hackennode] (10) at (1,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (11) at (1,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (12) at (1,1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (13) at (1,2) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (10) -- (11) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (11) -- (12) -- (13) {};
    \node[hackennode] (20) at (2,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (21) at (2,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (22) at (2,1) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (20) -- (21);
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (21) -- (22);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5] \node[inner sep=0] at (0,-1) {,\,};
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5]
    \draw[densely dashed] (-1,-1) -- (3,-1);
    \node[hackennode] (0) at (0,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (1) at (0,0) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (0) -- (1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (10) at (1,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (11) at (1,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (12) at (1,1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (13) at (1,2) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (10) -- (11) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (11) -- (12) -- (13) {};
    \node[hackennode] (20) at (2,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (21) at (2,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (22) at (2,1) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (20) -- (21);
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (21) -- (22);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5] \node[inner sep=0] at (0,-1) {,\,};
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.65ex,scale=0.5]
    \draw[densely dashed] (-1,-1) -- (3,-1);
    \node[hackennode] (0) at (0,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (2) at (0,1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (3) at (0,2) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (0) -- (1) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (1) -- (2) -- (3) {};
    \node[hackennode] (10) at (1,-1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (11) at (1,0) {};
    \node[hackennode] (12) at (1,1) {};
    \node[hackennode] (13) at (1,2) {};
    \draw[hackenline,blue] (10) -- (11) {};
    \draw[hackenline,red] (11) -- (12) -- (13) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\right \} \]
}% End group with \Large
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to format your code to make it a easier to read, and removed some unnecessary stuff in the preamble. It's great that you showed a working example, but it's usually a good idea to include only the relevant portion of the code. See this question for more information: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for editing it...I tried to take out all the irrelevant garbage, but I honestly didn't know what some of the preamble stuff was...

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" (see the checkmark below the score) if you are satisfied with the solution. This will help others with similar problems to see what worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you want but it's easy to add a label below axes, something like this

```
\draw[densely dashed] (-1,-1) -- node[below] {b)} (3,-1);
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: @Hendrik: Did it!

Comment: Thanks! (And sorry that I orphaned your comment by deleting mine.) A tip for the next image: Use `png` instead of `jpg`; this gives much better quality for this kind of image.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for, and it's a much simpler solution than I was trying.